# Portable View Engine Options (PHP / ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, codeigniter, cakephp, template-engine

With MVC possible in both ASP.NET MVC and PHP (CodeIgniter, CakePHP etc) what are the options when it comes to using a view engine that could work with both platforms, enabling copy/paste without any changes? Ones I can think of are:

- [NHaml](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/) / [PHPHaml](http://phphaml.sourceforge.net/) (not updated for 3 years though) / [PHamlP](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/)
   I am assuming this works with CodeIgniter or CakePHP, but haven't looked into it in great depth

Any more? Will add to list if there are any more.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Maybe a cross platform CMS, where modules/plugins could be portable (if they were done with just templates and JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

I can't really think of any, but [PHPHaml](http://phphaml.sourceforge.net/) is definitely recommended.

You could try building your own, using .Replace function. Since CodeIgniter has [Template Parser Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html)

```
string news = "test news template {content} bye";
news = news.Replace("{content}","test content");
```